# Data-Trigger Binding not working as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have an style which defines a template for content controls.

For all controls that have the content property null, I'd like to show text saying the control is empty... but the xaml below is not working, does anybody know why?

```
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="style">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentControl.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <TextBlock Background="Blue">EMPTY!</TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

<ContentControl Content="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource style}" />
```

It's not showing me the text 'EMPTY!'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="style">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="ContentControl.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <TextBlock Background="Blue">EMPTY!</TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>     
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource style}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I don´t know why its not working at design time.... only at runtime...I try to close and open VS...the window is still blank....

Comment: Yes that behaviour occurs for me too. I would suggest either hand rolling your XAML or using Blend. The VS designer leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: @devdigital: "leaves a lot to be desired", that's a very nice euphemism you have there.

Comment: @H.B. Yes, it's the only one that passed the swear filter

Answer (score 2):

**Your code works.** Take that GUI designer of yours and throw it out the window.

Answer (score -1):

simply change your textblock values from between context to property text="empty" like

```
  <TextBlock Background="Blue" Text="Empty"></TextBlock>
```

[image]

Comment: This makes no difference, it's entirely equivalent

Comment: <TextBlock Background="Blue" Text="Empty"></TextBlock> or <TextBlock Background="Blue" >EMpty</TextBlock> are the same.... both should work.... my problem is that the content is null and the controltemplate is not been called.......the datatrigger condition is not true...and it should be true....

Comment: both of the conditions are working for me in design and run time